# VB Script - Add If/Else to newMail.CC?

Tags: email, vbscript, hta

I'm creating a VB Script form that a user will fill out and send to one person. However, if one option is selected as 'high priority' I need it to CC another individual as well.

I'm a little rusty with VB, but this is what I have so far:

```
If priority.Value = "High priority" Then
    newMail.CC = "email@domain.com"
Else
    newMail.CC = ""
End If

newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
newMail.Body = MessageBody & MessageText
newMail.RecipIents.Add(ToAddress)
newMail.BCC = "email@domain.com"
newMail.Send
```

Will something like this work? Or how would I pass a variable to the newMail.CC option so that the additional person would get copied?

Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Comment: You need to state what `newMail` actually is (what object/class/api etc)

Comment: Have you tried running your code..? It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the insight. I kept getting an error saying that newMail.CC is required. I didn't have it set as a variable, and thought it would just be automatically recognized. I changed it to the following and it works:

```
Dim ccEmail
If priority.Value = "High priority" Then
    ccEmail = "email@domain.com"
Else
    ccEmail = ""
End If

newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
newMail.Body = MessageBody & MessageText
newMail.RecipIents.Add(ToAddress)
newMail.CC = ccEmail
newMail.Send
```

Thanks for the help!! :)